# accesslog websphere how to generate

Tags: websphere

need to trace client ip and how they are accessing the App on websphere app server.
how to turn on the access.log (or similar thing) in WAS

Answer (score 5):

This is configured at Application servers > server name > HTTP error and NCSA access logging.

You also need to enabled the logging in the inbound web channel under:
Servers > Application Servers > server > Web Container Transport Chains > HTTP Inbound Channel

Have a look at:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/utrb_httperrlogs.html

hth.